# Reveal text on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide my `<h2>` element until the user hovers over the image.

So when the user moves the cursor over the image, it will reveal the word 'Drinks' over the image. I'd like the text centered over the image too.

Can someone show me how to achieve this in CSS?

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/hj3xrumo/

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

li h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Test
</h1>

<li class="product-category product first">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/370x370" alt="Drinks" width="370" height="370" />
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">Drinks</h2>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/hj3xrumo/2/

Comment: That's almost exactly right, however, dream world it would load the text in the centre of the image.

Comment: Like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/hj3xrumo/4/

Comment: Exactly :-) Do you know why it flickers when I hover over the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;display:none;` to `h2` and make it `display: block` on `img:hove`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

li h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  display: none;
  margin:0;
}

li a:hover h2 {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product-category product first">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/370x370" alt="Drinks" width="370" height="370" />
      <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">Drinks</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help, don't forget to mark answer 

Comment: @AbhishekPandey In above codes when user hover h2 tag it flickers, so you can change li img:hover+h2 to li a:hover > h2

Comment: @frnt Thank you for correction, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
h2{
  display:none;
}
img:hover ~ h2{
  display:block;
}
```

Updated fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hj3xrumo/1/).

Answer (score 0):

use `img + h2` + is used for the next child

```css
li {
list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
li h2 {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}
.woocommerce-loop-category__title{
display:none;
}
img:hover + .woocommerce-loop-category__title{
display:block;
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>
Test
</h1>

<li class="product-category product first">
 <a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/370x370" alt="Drinks" width="370" height="370" />
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">Drinks</h2>
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this will work

```css
li {list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:370px;height:370px;position:relative;}
li a h2{
position:absolute;
top:40%;
left:40%;
trasnform:translate(-50%,-50%);
text-align:center;}
.imgbox:hover + h2{
  visibility:hidden
}
```

```html
<li class="product-category product first">
 <a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/370x370" alt="Drinks" class="imgbox" width="370" height="370" />
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">Drinks</h2>
 </a>
</li>
```